# What is the purpose of a filter consisting of a capacitor and two inductors?

Tags: filter

I have the following filter in a single device:

[image: Schematic]

It looks like a ceramic capacitor, but with 3 legs, and also states capacitance like such capacitor (only 103 printed).

What is the typical purpose of such filter? How would it usually be connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bulkhead feed-through capacitor with parasitic or intentional inductance: -

[image]

If it is this type of component it is used for passing signals through bulkhead plates (inside enclosures) between circuits. It's usually classified as an EMC component.

If it is a regular looking PCB component then it's still a filter that is intended (usually) to remove unwanted high frequency noise. The centre pin will usually be grounded and the two outer pins are for passing a signal in and out of a circuit. It's usually bi-directional.

Answer (score 1):

This is a T-Filter.

They are often used in power lines to attenuate a certain frequency. Usually for the purpose of reducing EMI susceptibility (or generation). See this [example from TDK](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/84891.pdf).

You select the specific type to attenuate your problem signal.

You would connect the power via two inductive connections. The cap is usually grounded.